# Generate Documentation for JSF 2 composite components

Tags: jsf, documentation, facelets, composite-component, documentation-generation

I'm looking to generate documentation for a custom JSF 2 composite component library.  The composite components are not referenced in any faces-config.xml file, but rather the .xhtml files for the composite components are stored in META-INF/resources and use the new composite:interface tag to define the interface.

For JSP tag libraries, documentation can be generated using https://taglibrarydoc.dev.java.net/ and I'm wondering if there is something similar for my JSF 2 composite component library.

Comment: Related: [How to generate facelets documentation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1612932)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [OmniFaces Vdldoc](http://vdldoc.omnifaces.org) to generate documentation from your `<cc:interface>` tags (or the documentation in `taglib.xml` files).

Say your composite components reside in the `/META-INF/resources/myLib` folder. You would then need a `myLib.taglib.xml`-file in the `META-INF` folder like this:

```
<facelet-taglib>
    <description>Your description</description>
    <namespace>http://example.com/myLib</namespace>
    <short-name>my</short-name>
    <composite-library-name>myLib</composite-library-name>
</facelet-taglib>
```

(For a more complete example, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130745/composite-components-in-an-external-jar-are-not-recognized-in-netbeans))

You can now use Vdldoc to generate your documentation:

```
java -jar vdldoc-2.1.jar myLib.taglib.xml
```

**Update:**
If your project uses maven there is now [vdldoc-maven-plugin](https://matinh.github.io/vdldoc-maven-plugin/) to easily integrate it into your build. Basically just add it to the `<reporting>`-section of your `pom.xml`:

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.github.matinh.vdldoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>vdldoc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

And run `mvn site` to generate the documentation. See the plugin's homepage for more details.

Answer (score 0):

rich-faces component development kit provides documentation annotations
http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesCDKannotations

--kiran.kumar

Comment: That's not really applicable for JSF 2 composite components though.